# Firebase Cloud Messaging - how with it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to bring FCM to my project. I have added Firebase support to my Flutter project and first wanted to try to send a test notification from Firebase Composer. I've got a device token by running `await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()` and used this token to send a message. Here I have one question and one problem.

Question: every time I restart the application I get a new token. Does it mean the token is active only when application is active? My primary goal is to deliver notification to the application when it's not active. Would old tokens work?

Problem: After I sent the test message I haven't received anything on the device even when application is active. Should anything be done on the device side except getting FCM token?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found answer to the question.
According to [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens?authuser=0):

> Also, it's important to save the token to the server and update the
> timestamp whenever it changes, such as when:
>
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

I didn't really just restart the app but reinstalled it.

As for the receiving I should've carefully read [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive?authuser=0) on receiving messages on the device. It describes what has to be done quite well